# running a program with wildcards as arguments

Tags: c, command-line-arguments

So I have the below code:

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    int a=1;

    while(argv[a] != NULL)
    {
    printf("\nargv[a] = %s\n", argv[a]); 
    execl("/bin/ls", "ls", argv[a], NULL);
    a++;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

I want to list three files called tickets1.lot, tickets2.lot, tickets3.lot. But when I run the program this way:

*./code ../input/*.lot*

I only get the first one listed:

argv[a] = ../input/tickets1.lot

../input/tickets1.lot

Is there anything wrong in my while loop condition?

Comment: My man page says "If successful, this function does not return to the calling process."

Comment: What you want is to fork&exec a child process to perform the specified work, and your parent process should wait for the child(ren) to finish, and as each finishes, start the next (or you could start multiple children at once).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*I only get the first one listed: ?* Thats because you didn't understood `execl()` correctly. very first time `execl()` replaces current process( `a.out`) with new process & done, loop will not iterate again as there is no process running.

you should create the child process using `fork()` & run `execl()` in each child process. Also instead of  `argv[a] != NULL` use `argc`.

Sample code

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
        int a = 0;
        while(++a < argc) { /* check this condition, how many process are there, that many times  it should iterate */
                printf("\nargv[a] = %s\n", argv[a]); 
                if(fork()) { /*every time parent process PCB replaced by /bin/ls process */
                        execl("/bin/ls", "ls", argv[a], NULL);
                        //a++; /*this will not execute */
                }
                else
                        ;
        }
        return 0;
}
```

From the manual page of `execl()` family function

> The  exec()  family of functions replaces the current process image
>          with a new process image. And The exec() functions return only if an  error  has  occurred.

So what ever you do after `execl()` call will execute only if error has occurred. for e.g

```
execl("/bin/ls", "ls", NULL); /* ls is the new process, old process is a.out if you are not creating process using fork() */ 
a++; /* this will not execute bcz above statement replaces a.out process with new process called ls */
```

Answer (score -3):

Try doing this!

```
#include <iostream>

int main(int argc, char** argv) 
{
    std::cout << "Have " << argc << " arguments:" << std::endl;

    for (int i = 0; i < argc; ++i)
    {
        std::cout << argv[i] << std::endl;
    }
}
```

Comment: "You know nothing, Jon Snow." (That is C++ code, but this question is tagged C. Also, it has nothing to do with not having enough arguments; it's a misunderstanding about the `execl` function.)

Comment: @ChronoKitsune "Winter is coming" :)